# What technological benefit do table and column aliases provide

Tags: sql

Besides multiple self joins on a table.

**What technological benefit do table and column aliases provide?**

From my research column and table aliases only help readability (if you exclude the self join scenario)

My example of multiple self join

```
SELECT TOP 1 s2.y, s3.a
FROM x AS s1
INNER JOIN x AS s2 ON s1.y = s2.y
INNER JOIN x as S3 ON s2.z = S3.z
```

The reason why the question, I am working with a system that has its own Sql wrapper generating SQL Code. I have had some issues with how the alias system is setup. Since the system generates all SQL code itself it wouldn't matter to the system to generate fully qualified names vs aliases.

Comment: What do you mean by "technological benefit"?

Comment: You answered your own question,there are no speed gains.

Comment: Why do they have to provide any other benefits beyond the ones you've already identified in your question?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not a sql guru and was checking if there was some other benefit to using an alias.

Comment: @DStanley I mean speed gains, storage gains, some sort of performance gain

Comment: @juergend I do not know, if you do let me know

Comment: @gh9 No, No, and No.

Comment: I guess I shall close the question then. Thank you everyone for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified self-joins as one place where table aliases are strictly required.

Additionally, table and field aliases make it easier to work with RDBMS systems in scenarios where you generate SQL dynamically. Rather than having to parse the schema to identify possible collisions, you could generate unique aliases for your tables and fields to force a specific interpretation of the data model. Aliases are not strictly required in this case, but they make your code easier to write and to understand.

> I have had some issues with how the alias system is setup. Since the system generates all SQL code itself it wouldn't matter to the system to generate fully qualified names vs aliases.

That is correct, as long as your system does not need to generate self-joins.

Finally, table aliases help with typing in cases when humans interact with RDBMS manually through query debuggers and other analysis tools. Again, the aliases are not required here, but they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Aliases
>
> SQL aliases are used to give a database table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.
>
> Basically aliases are created to make column names more readable.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

So they don't serve as a "technological benefit", but what they do is that you write a query, join 6 tables together (each table has a name like [ohmygodwhoeverdesignedmeshouldhavewrittenanovel] which you call with an alias as t1). Finishing your query, it runs fine, you feel good for what you have achieved, and you can easily tell what table holds the info you are looking for